# Use eclipse as subversion local copy GUI?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have a working local copy of a remote svn server. I access this server via ssh with  ProxyCommand in my .ssh/config file since it isn't directly reachable.
What I would like to do is using eclipse to browse my local copy of svn, make changes and commit them instead of using the command line. It would be like using eclipse as a gui for this svn local copy.
Is this possible without creating yet  another local copy of my repo. ? If so, could you tell me which steps I should make because I am a bit lost here...

I am running an ubuntu 12.10 bow, with eclipse 3.8. I have installed subversive and svnKit connector.